# Are the verb strings the ProcessStartInfo.Verbs propery returns for Standard Canonical Verbs different based on culture?

Tags: c#, windows, shell-verbs

Here [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> Canonical Verbs
>
> Applications are generally responsible for providing localized display strings for the verbs they define. However, to provide a degree of language independence, the system defines a standard set of commonly used verbs called canonical verbs. A canonical verb is never displayed to the user, and can be used with any UI language. The system uses the canonical name to automatically generate a properly localized display string. For instance, the open verb's display string is set to Open on an English system, and to the German equivalent on a German system.

My question is will the ProcessStartInfo.Verbs property always return the same string for standard canonical verbs (open, print, edit) regardless of the OS culture?  For example, if print is a verb option will it always return "print" as one of the strings and not the French/Spanish/Chinese/etc equivalent?

I understand that for non standard verbs it's up to the user to provide the culture and I'd imagine in those cases that the Verbs property would return the culture specific string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the point is that the values in `ProcessStartInfo.Verbs` are basically just keys into cultural files. They should be the same in all cultures - or rather, the culture doesn't affect the list of verbs.

You can tell this from the examples: "Printto" isn't something you'd display to a user, for example.

Comment: Oh they are "keys". I didn't clue in.  Sound simple once you explained it.  Thanks.  So this is true for the non standard verbs also, its just that the user is responsible for providing the culture strings?